# How to call Powershell script and pass parameters from C# windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, windows-forms-designer

I want to call powershell script which accepts some parameters from c# windows form.

For Example :- I have powershell script which accepts 2 parameters and i have a windows form with two textbox and a submit button. i want to pass parameters to powershell script from these two textboxes. When i press the submit button it will call the powershell script and run it on powershell terminal and also show result in powershell terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example for powershell script, that gives you ASCII code for char. Assuming you have richTextbox1 for showing output of the script and that you have button1 which you trigger it to run - here is the code:

```
        public void RunPowershell()
        {
            var ps1File = @"C:\asc.ps1";

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = $@"& '{ps1File}' f";
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            richTextBox1.Text = $"Output: {output}{Environment.NewLine}Errors = {errors}";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunPowershell();
        }
```

This will give ascii code for char 'f'.

Bellow is the PS script attached to example:

```
function Syntax {
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Asc.ps1,  Version 1.00"
    Write-Host "Returns the numeric ASCII value for the specified character"
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Usage:   " -NoNewline
    Write-Host "ASC.PS1  char" -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Returns: Numeric ASCII value of " -NoNewline
    Write-Host "char" -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Notes:   The ASCII value is written to Standard Output (usually the screen)"
    Write-Host "         as well as returned as `"errorlevel`""
    Write-Host "         If more than 1 character is passed on the command line, only the first"
    Write-Host "         character will be used, the remainder of the string will be ignored."
    Write-Host "         The `"errorlevel`" will equal the ASCII value, or 0 if no parameter"
    Write-Host "         was passed, or -1 in case of errors or for this help"
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Credits: Code to pass exit code as `"errorlevel`" to the calling batch file"
    Write-Host "         or PowerShell script by Serge van den Oever:"
    Write-Host "         weblogs.asp.net/soever/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script" -ForegroundColor DarkGray
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Written by Rob van der Woude"
    Write-Host "http://www.robvanderwoude.com"

    $Host.SetShouldExit( -1 )
    Exit
}

if ( $args.Length -eq 1 ) {
    if ( $args[0] -eq "/?" ) {
        Syntax
    } else {
        $input = $args[0]
    }
} else {
    Syntax
}

if ( $input -eq "" ) { $input = [string][char]0 }

[char]$char = $input[0]

Write-Host ([byte]$char) -NoNewline

# Pass exit code to calling batch or PowerShell script, by Serge van den Oever
# https://weblogs.asp.net/soever/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script
$Host.SetShouldExit( [byte]$char )
Exit
```

Save it to disk `C`, call it `asc.ps1` --> and you have working example.

Comment: Thanks for helping. your solution is nice but as i said in description that i want output in powershell terminal not in any textbox.

Comment: i tried your above example and it shows error:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Comment: Do you have file at this path: C:\asc.ps1?

Comment: Have you powershell installed? Which windows version do you have?

Comment: see i have windows 10 and powershell version is 7.0.0

Comment: When you open Command line and hit powershell - what do you see?

Answer (score -1):

Just start powershell.exe with parameters

To start any external application you may want to check how is working Process.

[Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2)